# How to add multiple cart buttons with multiple quantities in cart Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have added to add 3 to cart and add to cart buttons.In this buttons, I clicked add 3 to cart added 3 quantities and add to cart button also added 3 quantities.My requirement is only added 3 to cart button add only 3 quantities and remaining buttons added only one quantity.Can you please help me?
for example is below.
Add 3 to cart->add 3 quantities
Add to cart->add one quantity
Buy now ->add one quantity
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

**3 Qty:**

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product, array('qty' => 3)); ?>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product, array('qty' => 3)); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add 3')?></a>
```

**Buy Now:**

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productBuyNowForm.submit(this)"> <span><span>Buynow</span></span></button>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage')?>" name="return_url" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var productBuyNowForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
    productBuyNowForm.submit = function (button, url) {
    if (this.validator.validate()) {
        var form = this.form;
        var oldUrl = form.action;
        alert(form.action);
        if (url) {
            form.action = url;
        }

        /* add return Url */
        var inputreturn= document.createElement("input");
        inputreturn.type = "hidden";
        inputreturn.name = "return_url";
        inputreturn.value = "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage')?>";
        document.getElementById('product_addtocart_form').appendChild(inputreturn);
        /* add return Url */
        // Append a line break 
        var e = null;
        try {
            this.form.submit();
        } catch (e) {
        }
        this.form.action = oldUrl;
        if (e) {
            throw e;
        }

        if (button && button != 'undefined') {
            button.disabled = true;
        }
    }
}.bind(productBuyNowForm);  
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @ prince , Where 3 quantity code add <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product, array('qty' => 3)); ?>

Comment: Can you please tell me file path and particular place where code added?

Comment: `app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Comment: Hi, I have already buy now code added it is working.But my requirement is added 3 to cart button how to add and click add 3 to cart button only add 3 quantities.Can you please help me?

Comment: Look my adit now

Comment: I don't understand can you please send me the code?

Comment: paste `<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product, array('qty' => 3)); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add 3')?></a>` in `app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml ` and you'll have your add 3 button, when you click on it he add automatically 3 qty of the product to cart

Comment: Hi @ Prince, I need your help. How to add discount price more than one quantity.Can you please help me?